# Assign a queue item from a view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've created a dashboard with two views of a queue, one with items that I am working on, and one with items that are available for me to work on (unassigned):

[image: my queue view]

From this view I wish to assign one of the available items to myself. The only way I can see of doing this is clicking the 'See the records associated with this view' button:

[image]

And then in this new window selecting the record, clicking 'WORK ON' and the assigning it to me:

[image: work on]

So my question is, is it possible to have the 'WORK ON' button available in the dashboard so I don't have to look at the associated records view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to have buttons available on a dashboard well not in CRM 2013 anyway, would be a great feature if anyone has a potential workaround.